# Make directory for every category id in table

Tags: php, mkdir, do-while

I would like to create some 1000 directories with php for each category id in a Mysql table. The function needs to check whether the directory's name (id) already exists before creating one.
How do I do that?

Comment: PHP manual: [`is_dir()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php) - Tells whether the filename is a directory

Comment: PHP manual: [`mkdir()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php) - Creates a directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (error checks avoided for simplicity):

```
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "mysql_user", "mysql_password");
mysql_select_db("mydbname");
$sql = "SELECT id FROM   sometable";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    mkdir($row['id']); // will return false is directory already exists
}
mysql_free_result($result);
```

If you still need to check whether directory exists or not, you can use [`stat`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stat.php) (or lstat) function.

Comment: Works great! Tried to chmod the folder at the same time but I cannot set it to 777 'cos the owner is apache. Is there a workaround?

Comment: mmmmm... depends on your security settings. I would set STICKY BIT on parent directory.